# Obtaining equation of circles

Tags: circles, tangent-line

Find the equation of a circle  tangent to both x and y axes passing through (-2,1) and

also

Find the equation of another circle with center (5,3) and tangent to the x axis only.

Comment: Hint 1: the center of the circle lies on one of the lines $x=\pm y$. Hint 2: What must the radius of this circle be?

Comment: Okay the radius must be the line perpendicular to the tangent

Comment: While the center of the circle is equidistant from the line

Comment: The second hint was for the second circle. You can read the radius length directly from the problem statement.

Comment: mobius transformations are conform

Comment: Well I'm even confused here and things are getting complex. I do need help now

Comment: @MichaelUmande Expanding on amd's hints: since the center of the circle lies on $y=\pm x$, we can express the centre in terms of a single variable. But then knowing that the tangent points are perpendicular to the centre of the circle, we can express the radius in terms of that same variable. But then if the equation of the circle is an equation in a single variable…

Comment: @MichaelUmande Please roll back if my edit was due to incorrect understanding of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the first question:**
Using the fact that $(-2,1)$ is in the second quadrant, the circle is of the form $(x+r)^2+(y-r)^2 = r^2$.

**For the second question:**
The circle is of the form $(x-5)^2+(y-3)^2=r^2$.